# jQuery onclick function: Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, undefined

Edit: I guess part of this is an issue of me being inexperienced with Drupal. I added a javascript file to site.info, so that it will be added to every page. This is all the file contains:

```
(function ($){
$("#ctl00_btnSearch001").on("click", function(){
       var searchVal = $("#ctl00_txtSearch").val();
       window.location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.org/search/?sa=Search&q=" + searchVal;         
    });    
})(jQuery);
```

When the site loads, it gets compiled into this larger script, which looks like this in the debugger:

```
    (function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.titlebar = {
    init: function(context, settings) {
      // Using percentage font size to easily increase/decrease page font size
      var baseFontSize = 100;
      $('.pgc-font-size a').click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('increase')) {
          if(baseFontSize < 150)
            baseFontSize += 20;
          $('.pg-content-body p').css('font-size', baseFontSize+'%');
        } else {
          if(baseFontSize > 70)
            baseFontSize -= 10;
          $('.pg-content-body p').css('font-size', baseFontSize+'%');
        }
      });

      // Print button
      $('.pgc-print a').click(function() {
        window.print();
      })
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
// There's a problem with our jQuery loading before the ingested site's
// jQuery which is causing jQuery plugins to break (the "once" plugin in this case).
// I'm using this workaround for now
jQuery(function() {
  Drupal.behaviors.titlebar.init();
});;
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.giftTypes = {
    init: function() {
      // Gift details accordion
      $('.pg-gift-details .accordion-items').css('display', 'none');
      $('.pg-gift-details .accordion-switch').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
          $(this).find('span').removeClass('icon-arrow-up').addClass('icon-arrow-down');
          $('.pg-gift-details .accordion-items').slideUp('slow');
          $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Hide', 'Show More'));
          $(this).removeClass('open');
        } else {
          $(this).find('span').removeClass('icon-arrow-down').addClass('icon-arrow-up');
          $('.pg-gift-details .accordion-items').slideDown('slow');
          $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Show More', 'Hide'));
          $(this).addClass('open');
        }
      })
    }
  }
}(jQuery));
// There's a problem with our jQuery loading before the ingested site's
// jQuery which is causing jQuery plugins to break (the "once" plugin in this case).
// I'm using this workaround for now
jQuery(function() {
  Drupal.behaviors.giftTypes.init();
});;
(function ($){
$("#ctl00_btnSearch001").on("click", function(){
    var searchVal = $("#ctl00_txtSearch").val();
    alert(searchVal);
    window.location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.org/search/?sa=Search&q=" + searchVal;
  });
})(jQuery);
;
```

You can see my little script at the bottom there. It says there's something wrong with the first line, but I'm not sure what the problem is. What change would I need to make to my javascript file to make sure it compiles right?

---

I'm probably overlooking a really simple type, but I can't see what's wrong with my jQuery.

This is the part that's not working:

```
(function ($){
    $("#ctl00_btnSearch001").on("click", function(){
        var searchVal = $("#ctl00_txtSearch").val();
        window.location.href = "http://www.website.org/search/?sa=Search&q=" + searchVal;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I have jQuery on my site, I know I do because this it's used earlier in the code with no problem. The error is showing in the debugger on the first line, '$("#ct100_btnSearch001").on("click", function(){ '.  Here is a larger section of the script page:

```
(function($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.giftTypes = {
        init: function() {
            // Gift details accordion
            $('.pg-gift-details .accordion-items').css('display', 'none');
            $('.pg-gift-details .accordion-switch').click(function() {
                if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
                    $(this).find('span').removeClass('icon-arrow-up').addClass('icon-arrow-down');
                    $('.pg-gift-details .accordion-items').slideUp('slow');
                    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Hide', 'Show More'));
                    $(this).removeClass('open');
                } else {
                    $(this).find('span').removeClass('icon-arrow-down').addClass('icon-arrow-up');
                    $('.pg-gift-details .accordion-items').slideDown('slow');
                    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Show More', 'Hide'));
                    $(this).addClass('open');
                }
            })
        }
    }
}(jQuery));

jQuery(function() {
    Drupal.behaviors.giftTypes.init();
});;
(function($) {
    $("#ctl00_btnSearch001").on("click", function() {
        var searchVal = $("#ctl00_txtSearch").val();
        alert(searchVal);
        window.location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.org/search/?sa=Search&q=" + searchVal;
    });
})(jQuery);;
```

Comment: Does the line with `.val();` give the error?

Comment: Why are you accessing the DOM outside of a document.ready?

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: no, the error is on $("#ct100_btnSearch001").on("click", function(){

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [jQuery update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) Module.

If you are using Drupal 6, you are not be able to use `on` function.

One option is to include your custom version of jQuery in your page.tpl.php, another option (not recommended) is to use `live`, but now is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a function to an event use two way:

1.use bind() method and the event name as the first argument

```
$( "#foo" ).bind( "click", function() {
alert( "User clicked on 'foo.'" );
});
```

or

2.just use the event method

```
$( "#foo" ).click( function() {
alert( "User clicked on 'foo.'" );
});
```

The problem of your code is that there isn't a `on` event.
 ref http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Comment: I changed it to $("#ct100_btnSearch001").click(function(){ but it still won't compile. I think it thinks that jquery is undefined, but it's used elsewhere on the page so that seems weird to me.

Comment: do you really have a object of id `ct100_btnSearch001` ?

Comment: may be you should put that in $(document).ready() , have you ?

Answer (score 0):

If ctl00_btnSearch001 is a correct id for what ever you are trying to click. Try changing it to this:

```
(function ($){
    $(document).on("click", "#ctl00_btnSearch001", function(){
       var searchVal = $("#ctl00_txtSearch").val();
       window.location.href = "http://www.mywebsite.org/search/?sa=Search&q=" + searchVal;         
    });    
})(jQuery);
```